# Print all numbers between two given numbers

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a Bash script which that takes in two integers and outputs all the numbers in between the two. It would look something like this:

Input:

```
bash testScript 3 10
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

This is some code that I wrote that I thought would work but I haven't had much luck getting it to work yet.

```
read myvar
read myvar2
while [ $myvar -le myvar2 ]
do
    echo $myvar
    myvar=$(($myvar+1))

    //timer in-between numbers 

    sleep .5
done
```

Comment: Instead of saying that something doesn't work, describe *why* it doesn't work -- what you expect, and what you're getting instead. (See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in general, and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in particular).

Comment: BTW, use the `{}` button after you've selected a region of code to format it for inclusion as such.

Comment: One hint, by the way: Command-line arguments are separate from input. `read` reads from stdin, whereas arguments passed to your script on its command line are in the array `"$@"`, and can also be referenced via `"$1"`, `"$2"`, etc.

Comment: seq does what you need: `seq 3 10`

Comment: @LarsFischer, `seq` is not a POSIX-standardized tool, nor is it built into bash, so there's no guarantee that it'll be available (or have any particular behavior) on a given system.

Comment: you have typos in your codes, such as while [ $myvar -le myvar2 ]. myvar2 should be $myvar2.

Answer (score 2):

Bash supports `c` style for loops using a [double parenthesis](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html#DBLPARENSREF) construct:

```
$ for ((x=3; x<=10; x++)); { echo $x; }
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Or, brace expansion:

```
$ for i in {3..6}; do echo $i; done
3
4
5
6
```

Problem with brace expansion is you need to use `eval` to use variables...

---

A common GNU utility for this is [seq](https://linux.die.net/man/1/seq) but it is not POSIX, so may not be on every *nix. If you want to write a similar function in Bash, it would look like this:

```
my_seq ()   
# function similar to seq but with integers
# my_seq [first [incr]] last
{
    incr=1
    start=1
    if [[ $# -gt 2 ]]; then
        start=$1
        incr=$2
        end=$3
    elif [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
        start=$1
        end=$2
    else    
        end=$1
    fi
    for ((x=start; x<=end; x+=incr)); { echo $x; }
}
```

Then call that with 1, 2 or 3 arguments:

```
$ my_seq 30 10 60
30
40
50
60
```

Answer (score 1):

with brace expansion

```
$ echo {3..10} | tr ' ' '\n'
```

or for variables with `eval`

```
$ a=3; b=10; eval echo {$a..$b} | ...
```

or, if you have `awk`

```
$ awk -v s=3 -v e=10 'BEGIN{while(s<=e) print s++}'
```

Comment: You can't use this in a script though, if `3` and `10` are positional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use positional parameters:

```
myvar=$1
myvar2=$2

while [ $myvar -le $myvar2 ]
do
    echo $myvar
    myvar=$(($myvar+1))

    #timer in-between numbers 

    sleep .5
done
```

Output:

```
scottsmudger@ns207588:~ $ bash test 1 5
1
2
3
4
5
```

See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html

Answer (score 0):

Your posted codes are not aligned properly, not sure if it's your actual codes. But only problem other than the alignment is you missed a $ for myvar2 in the while statment.

```
read myvar
read myvar2

while [ $myvar -le $myvar2 ]
do

    echo $myvar
    myvar=$(($myvar+1))

    #//timer in-between numbers

    sleep .5

done
```